# replace text of a label which is in a node (dojo)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a wizard..in one pane i select an item...in second pane i enter the information..in the third pane i am display the item selected and the information like a summary..but what is happening is for the first time i get everything properly but if i go back and change the selected item or info...in the third pane...i am also getting the previous results..i want those labels to be replaced with the new selection and info..any ideas?

brief outline

3rd pane(say pane1) has 2 div elements(label1 and label2)...i am populating the innerHTML of the div with respective objects

```
var label1 = dojo.create("div", { innerHTML: ob.selecteditem},"pane1");
var label2 = dojo.create("div", { innerHTML: ob.information},"pane1");
```

how do i refresh the label text everytime...a user changes the selected item or the info?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually...i am destroying the div on calling the function and then writing to it...

```
Sample: function(obj1)
{
domConstruct.destroy("id1");
var label1 = domConstruct.create("div", { id: "id1", innerHTML: "item selected " }, "pane1");
}
```

hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your panes are part of the same DOM (no full page refreshes/iframes), you just need an onchange event handler for your select, and the textbox that you use to collect information. What are you using for the select widget and the info textbox?

use onchange event if you are using regular HTML elements (or onChange for dijit form elements) and do something like following:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("selectId"), 'onchange',
  function(evt) {
      dojo.byId("label1").innerHTML = evt.target.value;
  }
);
```